# how to generate automatic account no. in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc

if you have any code please send

i am working on a online banking project in spring MVC. i want to generate automatically account no for who create a new account .

when a new user create a account i want that is automatically generate the account no. for the user

my code is for create new account is

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/addCustomer")
public ModelAndView Customer(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    dao.add(user);
    return new ModelAndView("addAC");

}
```

Comment: Do it in `User` setter or auto increment in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Using DB:

- Create sequence and increment each time while inserting.
- Create trigger(plsql) and increment and insert while adding user info.

## 2. Using code:

Take current time in millisecond and have some format(For account no), concat and insert so it will be unique for each one.

Comment: Thanks Aarik Gowda